# Link a particular form with a drawn line?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a GIS application. I want to open a particular form with drawn lines. The form which will open  contains a textbox which is showing the length of the line. I am able to select the line. I am able to get the length of the line.

I want to link the form with each line. and the same form should be displayed whenever that line is selected. How can i do it?
should i go for serialization? or is there any good solution?

I know this is GIS related thing, but its more like a C# problem.

Code:

```
 private bool amDigitizing = false;

    //Coordiant
    private List<DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate> myDigitizedPoints = new List<DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate>();
    private List<DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate> myExtractedPoints = new List<DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate>();

   // DEM Layer
    private DotSpatial.Controls.MapRasterLayer demLyr;
    // Line Layer
    private DotSpatial.Controls.MapLineLayer LineLyr;
    FormTableEditor ft = new FormTableEditor();



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        appManager1.LoadExtensions();
        appManager1.CompositionContainer.ComposeParts(toolManager1);
    }



    private void map1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Coordinate c_mouse = map1.PixelToProj(new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y));
        Xstrip.Text = "X:" + Convert.ToString(c_mouse.X);
        Ystrip.Text = "Y:" + Convert.ToString(c_mouse.Y);

    }



    private void btnDraw_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //map1.Layers.Remove(LineLyr);
        }
        catch
        {
            // do nothing
        }

        // Start  a Drawing 
        MessageBox.Show(" Click on the map to draw, double click to stop drawing");
        amDigitizing = true;

        myDigitizedPoints = new List<DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate>();
        map1.FunctionMode = DotSpatial.Controls.FunctionMode.None;
    }

    private void map1_MouseClick_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        // digitizing
        if (amDigitizing == true)
        {
            DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate c = new DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate();
            System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point();
            p.X = e.X;
            p.Y = e.Y;
            c = map1.PixelToProj(p);

            //double[] s = c.ToArray();

            //StartX = s[0];
            //StartY = s[1];

            myDigitizedPoints.Add(c);

        }


    }



    int NoOfMines = 0;

    private void map1_MouseDoubleClick_1(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Double click ends digitizing

        if (amDigitizing == true)
        {
            DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate c = new DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate();
            System.Drawing.Point p = new System.Drawing.Point();
            p.X = e.X;
            p.Y = e.Y;
            c = map1.PixelToProj(p);
            myDigitizedPoints.Add(c);
            //double[] s = c.ToArray();

            //EndX = s[0];
            //EndY = s[1];
            amDigitizing = false;


            DotSpatial.Data.Feature f = new DotSpatial.Data.Feature(DotSpatial.Topology.FeatureType.Line, myDigitizedPoints);
            DotSpatial.Data.FeatureSet fs = new DotSpatial.Data.FeatureSet();
            fs.AddFeature(f);
            NoOfMines = NoOfMines +1 ;

            fs.Projection = map1.Projection;
            for (int i = 0; i < NoOfMines; i++)
            {
                fs.Name = "Mine Field" + NoOfMines.ToString();
            }


            //fs.SaveAs(GraphicsPathExt, true);
            //LineLyr = (DotSpatial.Controls.MapLineLayer)map1.AddLayer(GraphicsPathExt);
            LineLyr = (MapLineLayer)map1.Layers.Add(fs);




        }




   }




    // Length of the line

    private void mnuThin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LineLyr.Symbolizer.SetFillColor(Color.Red);
        LineLyr.Symbolizer.SetWidth(5.0);
        LineLyr.Symbolizer.SetOutline(Color.White, 1.0);
        map1.Refresh();

        IRaster r = (IRaster)map1.Layers[0].DataSet;

        IFeatureSet fs = LineLyr.DataSet;

        int np = 0;

        try
        {
            foreach (IFeature f in fs.Features)
            {
                np += f.Coordinates.Count * 100;
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        double[] plotX = new double[np - 99];
        double[] plotY = new double[np - 99];

        double x1= 0, y1 = 0, x2 = 0 , y2 = 0 , dx = 0 , dy = 0, newx = 0, newy = 0;
        double z = 0;
        double TotalLength = 0.0;
        int i = 0;
        double[] Slope = new double[np / 100];



        foreach (IFeature f in fs.Features)
        {
            foreach (DotSpatial.Topology.Coordinate c in f.Coordinates)
            {
                x2 = c.X;
                y2 = c.Y;
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    dx = (x2 - x1) / 100;
                    dy = (y2 - y1) / 100;

                    newx = x1;
                    newy = y1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
                    {
                        TotalLength += Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(dx, 2) + Math.Pow(dy, 2));

                        z = demLyr.DataSet.GetNearestValue(newx, newy);

                        i += 1;
                    }

                }
                x1 = x2;
                y1 = y2;


                if (i == 0)
                {
                    z = demLyr.DataSet.GetNearestValue(newx, newy);

                    i += 1;
                    x1 = x2;
                    y1 = y2;
                }
            }
        }
        //Length of the line
        ft.textBox1.Text = TotalLength.ToString();


    }




   //Selection of layer
    private void customizeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IMapLayer layerSelect = appManager1.Map.Layers.SelectedLayer;
        if (layerSelect == LineLyr)
        {
            ft.Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is it on different forms? Way too much code btw.

Comment: Because its requirement. I hate to add new forms. 
Sorry but i have to put all the code as i dont know the solution to my problem @yoryeNathan

Comment: You could wrap the line and share the reference between the forms, and let it implement INotifyPropertyChanged to update the UI. Or just inform the other form to refresh line after every change you make to it.

Comment: The related part is how i draw the line with mouse click and mouse double and select the line.

Comment: what about serialization? will it work in this particular scenario?

Comment: What does serialization have to do with any of this? How did you attempt to communicate between the two forms?

Comment: i though i could create xml file per line. 
and then read it through. . 
I globally declared the second form. .
  ft.textBox1.Text = TotalLength.ToString();

Comment: Pass a reference to the object. OOP is OP man.

Comment: will you please explain it.? i dont know how to pass a reference to the object ?

Comment: _"I want to link the form with each line"_ -- I don't understand the problem statement. What do you mean _specifically_ by "link"? Are you simply trying to get a single form, displaying the length of the line, to update its text when the selected line changes? If so, why not just change the displayed text when the selection changes. If not, what _are_ you trying to do? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: basically there is no selection change event available in the events panel of this particular dotspatial control knowns as legend. @peter duniho

Answer (score 0):

As Peter duniho mentioned in the comments of selection change event. 
i used that approach to link the form.

```
     DrawObject o = new DrawObject;
     Form1 f = new Form1(o);
     LegendItem li = new LegendItem();
     if (li.IsSelected == true)
     {
          f.Textbox1.Text = frontage.ToString();
          f.show();
     }
```